# How can I select all rows which have been inserted in the last day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// reset_password_emails
+----+----------+--------------------+-------------+
| id | id_user  |        token       | unix_time   |
+----+----------+--------------------+-------------+
| 1  | 2353     | 0c274nhdc62b9dc... | 1339412843  |
| 2  | 2353     | 0934jkf34098joi... | 1339412864  |
| 3  | 5462     | 3408ujf34o9gfvr... | 1339412894  |
| 4  | 3422     | 2309jrgv0435gff... | 1339412899  |
| 5  | 3422     | 34oihfc3lpot4gv... | 1339412906  |
| 6  | 2353     | 3498hfjp34gv4r3... | 1339412906  |
| 16 | 2353     | asdf3rf3409kv39... | 1466272801  |
| 7  | 7785     | 123dcoj34f43kie... | 1339412951  |
| 9  | 5462     | 3fcewloui493e4r... | 1339413621  |
| 13 | 8007     | 56gvb45cf3454g3... | 1339424860  |
| 14 | 7785     | vg4er5y2f4f45v4... | 1339424822  |
+----+----------+--------------------+-------------+
```

Each row is an email. Now I'm trying to implement a limitation for sending-reset-password email. I mean an user can achieve 3 emails per day *(not more)*.

So I need an query to check user's history for the number of emails:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM reset_password_emails WHERE token = :token AND {from not until last day}
```

How can I implement this:

```
. . . {from now until last day}
```

---

Actually I can do that like: `NOW() <= (unix_time + 86400)` .. But I guess there is a better approach by using `interval`. Can anybody tell me what's that?

Comment: what you have is absolutely perfect `NOW() <= (unix_time + 86400)`

Comment: by "last day" do you mean "24 hours before now" or "midnight to midnight of the previous day"?

Comment: @Bohemian 24 hours before now

Comment: @vkp actually it's not perfect, because it requires a calculation every row (which can be avoided)

Comment: @Bohemian..when you use a function to cast unix_time to timestamp that would require the function to be evaluated for each row too..correct?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, that's exactly what I was think of ..! I'm pretty sure there is a solution like `- interval 1 day` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression will work, but has 3 problems:

1. the way you've coded it means the subtraction must be performed for every row (performance hit)
2. because you're not using the raw column value, you couldn't use an index on the time column (if one existed)
3. it isn't clear to read

Try this:

```
unix_time > unix_timestamp(subdate(now(), interval '1' day))
```

here the threshold datetime is calculated *once* per query, so all of the problems above have been addressed.

See [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82da70/7)

Comment: Ok just as a note, this query needs an multiple column index on `(toke,unix_time)` or two separated indexes on `(token)` and `(unix_time)` columns?

Comment: Only one index can be used per table access, so you need the multiple column index.

Comment: Wrong .. The value of `unix_time` column is an integer number of seconds in the table above. But `ubdate(now(), interval '1' day)` returns a date-time format. So your equation won't work.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Seems correct *(what you said)*. I guess Bohemian should warp his condition into `unix_timestamp()` function.

Comment: @Shafizadeh OK. I assumed wrong. I've added a call to `unjx_tinestamp()` to convert the calculated date to epoch seconds. Thanks for picking this up.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your `unix_time` using `from_unixtime` function

```
select r.*
  from reset_password_emails r
 where now() <= from_unixtime(r.unix_time) - interval '1' day
```

Just add the extra filters you want.

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a7a9/3

It evaluates to no rows because your given data for `unix_time` field is all from 2011

Edited with a sqlfiddle that show the conversion:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a7a9/4

Comment: This still  has problems 1 and 2 mentioned in my answer

Comment: Yeah, I know.  Thank you for pointing it out. @Bohemian I just wanted to show a way to do it.